# How do I reverse the Y axis in ggplot's geom_tile?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is a graph.  How do I reverse the Y axis , so it reads down "a b" instead of "b a", while leaving the X axis alone?

[image: geom_tile]

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
levels = ordered(c('a', 'b'))
data = data.frame(x=ordered(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), levels=levels),
                  y=ordered(c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), levels=levels),
                  prob=c(0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6))
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=prob))
```

Comment: `ggplot(data, aes(x, forcats::fct_rev(y))) + geom_tile(aes(fill=prob))`

Answer (score 9):

I figured this out.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, ordered(y, levels=rev(levels)))) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=prob))
```

[image: geom_tile]